# Center font icons inside a html container

Tags: html, css, fonts, icons

I'm having trouble center the orange basketball inside this icon container.  You can view it from this link in the header of this event, [Website](http://basketball.exposureevents.com/27959/mayb-california-mo-basketball-tournament).  As you can see the basketball won't stay centered.  If I increate the size of the font it starts too.  Also if you look down at the bottom of the page I actually have the same setup, except the font is a little larger but looks just fine.  This should work even if I enlarge the font size.

[image]

**HTML**

```
<a title="MAYB Sanctioned Event" rel="nofollow" href="#mayb-sanctioned" class="btn"><i class="icon-ebt-container"><i class="icon-ebt-maybback"></i><i class="icon-ebt-maybmiddle"></i><i class="icon-ebt-maybfront"></i></i></a>
```

**CSS**

```
.icon-ebt-container {
    position: relative;
}
.icon-ebt-maybfront:before {
    color: #003F5F;
    content: "\69";
}

.icon-ebt-maybmiddle:before {
    color: #000000;
    content: "\70";
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    top: -2px;
}
```

Comment: Your website link is of localhost.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
    line-height:17px;
}
```

In your CSS, you have it set to normal.

Comment: Will this always work though if I enlarge the font size?

Answer (score 0):

You can center regardless of the size using something like the following:

```
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

The top and left move the element so its upper left corner is in the center, and then the transform moves it up by 50% of its height and left 50% of its width.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
    display: inline;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    line-height: normal;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background-image: none;
    background-position: 0% 0%;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

With:

```
[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
    display: inline;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 16px;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background-image: none;
    background-position: 0% 0%;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

Result: http://prntscr.com/6270fx